# What is the difference between BAW and SAW?

Tags: oscillator

TI has recently (?) released some **BAW** (*Bulk Acoustic Wave*) based resonators, but **SAW** (*Surface Acoustic Wave*) devices has been around for ages. Most often SAW are found in mobile RF filters.

[This](https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/analogwire/archive/2019/02/27/are-you-ready-for-baw?) gave me a littlke bit of insight, but not enough to claim I understand the diff.

**What is the difference between devices operating with SAW and BAW?**

Comment: I'd always taken BAW to be a parasitic problem that comes along with SAW (you can't avoid bulk propagation when all you want is surface.) But this sounds as though they flipped that coin and are trying to focus on the bulk response. The bulk responses include deep and surface-skimming, thickness resonance type, and leaked. Probably even more categories than that. I would tend to imagine they are focusing on the thickness-based bulk resonance. But I've no real idea. Have you looked for white papers on the topic?

Comment: I'm not going to do a link-only answer, so [here's](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Engineering_Acoustics/Piezoelectric_Acoustic_Sensor) a link-only comment. Basically SAW uses surface waves, and BAW uses bulk, or volume acoustic waves. SAW lends itself to the creation of complex filters by surface patterning of electrodes, and BAW to higher Qs of simple oscillator resonators.